# Excel: Deselect all radio buttons in a group

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button

I have a survey spreadsheet has a group of option buttons. If the user hasn't chosen one, I want them all to be deselected (or set to that greyed-out setting you can have in "TripleState"). If the user *has* chosen one, I'd still like to be able to clear them all (in case, for instance, he clicks one by mistake and isn't ready to answer yet.)

I know I can add another button as a "No Answer" choice, but on this sheet it would be a little inelegant.

Would it be simpler to use checkboxes instead, and make it so checking each box deselect the others (like radio buttons)? Deselecting would be the trivial part.

EDIT: Note the buttons are on a worksheet, not a userform.

Comment: Set all of the option buttons to false in order to "reset" your form.

Comment: not clear what's the event triggering the deselecting process. more: are the button on the worksheet or in a userform?

Comment: I don't know what should trigger the deselection. The only thing I could think of is a command button nearby.  The buttons are on a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite find a solution regarding option boxes however the following will work for check boxes:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    CheckBox2.Value = False
    CheckBox3.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    CheckBox1.Value = False
    CheckBox3.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    CheckBox1.Value = False
    CheckBox2.Value = False
End Sub
```

The above assumes 3 checkboxes for each survey selection. Just rename CheckBox1 CheckBox2 CheckBox3 to whatever you like, but remain consistent. The user will have to deselect every option they want to change however but will allow them to deselect all options and also embeds the option box behavior of only allowing one choice at a time.